# Having problem in alignment in the resume document class

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, cv, resume

I am using the document class "res" for making my CV and I have some problems in aligning the sections. Like in the below image, the **Address Lines** are not aligned with the **Test** in the **Research Interests**

[image: resume]

The code is given below. How to solve this problem?

```
\documentclass[line, margin]{res}
\makeatletter
\def\@classoptionslist{<class options except `margin` OR empty>}
\makeatother

\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{url}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true,allcolors=black}
\usepackage{hypcap}


\linespread{1.1}

%\topmargin=-0.45in
%\evensidemargin=0in
%\oddsidemargin=0in
%\textwidth=5.5in
%\textheight=9.0in
%\headsep=0.25in
%\hoffset=1in

 \geometry{
    a4paper,
    total={210mm,297mm},
    left=20mm,
    right=50mm,
    top=20mm,
    bottom=20mm,
 }

\begin{document}
    \name{My Name}

        \begin{resume}

        \vspace{0.5cm}          

            \section{\textsc{Contact Information}}
            \begin{tabular}{l l}
                \begin{tabular}{l}
                    c/o Address line 1 \\
                    Address Line 2 \\
                    City, Country
                \end{tabular} & 
                \begin{tabular}{l}
                    \textit{Cell:} \texttt {\href{tel:+xx xxx xxxx xxx}{{+xx xxx xxxx xxx}}}\\
                    \textit{Email:} \texttt{\href{mailto:test@test.com}{\nolinkurl{test@test.com}}}\\
                    \textit{LinkedIn:} \texttt{\url{linkedin.com/in/arbitraryurl}}
                \end{tabular}
            \end{tabular}

            \section{\textsc{Research Interests}}

            Test \\

            \section{\textsc{Education}}
            \textbf{M.Sc. in Test, Sept xxx - ongoing} \\
            University, Country


        \end{resume}


\end{document}
```

Comment: It's the `tabular` environment and its `\tabcolsep` spacing before `l` specifiers (well, actually before any specifier, unless explicitly *killed*)

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about the `res.cls` and I am unsure whether the `tabular` way is the best way to do this, but if `tabular` is used, one has to kill the additional column spacing left and right of a column specifier:

```
\begin{tabular}{@{}ll}
```

will remove the extra space of `6pt` (standard value of `\tabcolsep`) for the `tabular`s. This must be done in the outer as well in the first inner `tabular` environments.

```
\documentclass[line, margin]{res}
\makeatletter
\def\@classoptionslist{<class options except `margin` OR empty>}
\makeatother

\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{url}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true,allcolors=black}
\usepackage{hypcap}


\linespread{1.1}

%\topmargin=-0.45in
%\evensidemargin=0in
%\oddsidemargin=0in
%\textwidth=5.5in
%\textheight=9.0in
%\headsep=0.25in
%\hoffset=1in

 \geometry{
    a4paper,
    total={210mm,297mm},
    left=20mm,
    right=50mm,
    top=20mm,
    bottom=20mm,
 }

\begin{document}
    \name{My Name}

        \begin{resume}

    \vspace{0.5cm}          

        \section{\textsc{Contact Information}}
        \begin{tabular}{@{}l l}
            \begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
                c/o Address line 1 \\
                Address Line 2 \\
                City, Country
            \end{tabular} & 
            \begin{tabular}{l}
                \textit{Cell:} \texttt {\href{tel:+xx xxx xxxx xxx}{{+xx xxx xxxx xxx}}}\\
                \textit{Email:} \texttt{\href{mailto:test@test.com}{\nolinkurl{test@test.com}}}\\
                \textit{LinkedIn:} \texttt{\url{linkedin.com/in/arbitraryurl}}
            \end{tabular}
        \end{tabular}

        \section{\textsc{Research Interests}}

        Test \\

        \section{\textsc{Education}}
        \textbf{M.Sc. in Test, Sept xxx - ongoing} \\
        University, Country


    \end{resume}
\end{document}
```

[image]